# Why is Node Express Duplicating Static Content

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I have the following app.js file:

https://gist.github.com/manifestinteractive/393a4aae0c4ed4fb6bc2

When I look at files I am loading statically in the public folder via the operating system, they look correct, however, if I go to view them via the browser as intended for delivery through node express engine, the contents are duplicated.  Basically, it is taking the file and appending it to itself, which of course breaks the javascript.

Anyone know why this would be happening?  Suck a weird bug and I can't for the life of me put my finger on the cause.

For the record, I have tried looking everywhere for a solution. I've just not seen anyone talk about it.  A quick test shows that I can manually change the JavaScript file at the source, and refresh the code in the browser, and it will reflect the changes correctly, but it will still be displayed twice.

Thought it might be some weird issue where maybe I had multiple instances of Node running or something, as that MIGHT explain it... but nothing :(

If I find what it is, I will follow up with the issue immediately, but for the time being, I am likely just doing something stupid someone here might yell at me for... and I would gladly welcome it :)

Comment: Could you remove all code that's not relevant to the problem? It makes it a lot easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce the error with the least amount of code possible. A side benefit of doing so is that you might accidentally find the cause in the process.

Comment: Hmm...try moving express.static middleware after app.router middleware?

Comment: It is very unlikely that express append those files with themselves. Do you happen to have some build process or grunt tasks, which can modify those static assets?

Comment: @Mr_Mig That was the first thing I looked for was to see if there was some grunt process running in the background.  Oddly this seems to be related to a specific module getting loaded.  I started commenting out lines in the require('./models/init')(opts) path and seemed to have fixed the issue, but have zero idea why a specific model was causing the issue, since no grunt process was getting fired.

Comment: @ScottGress I did try what you suggested and it made no difference